# How can I remove all space between two images with a global option?

Tags: spacing, graphics

I want to include several images just below each other without vertical space. How can I do this by adding some code to the preamble (i.e. I want this setting globally). Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image1}

\includegraphics{image2}

\includegraphics{image3}

%% and a lot more images

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You see there is a little bit vertical space bewtween the pictures. But I want to have *no* vertical space at all.

Comment: Without *vertical image*? You mean *vertical space*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between lines is an additional `\interlineskip`. You have to kill this with `\offinterlineskip`, within a group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\offinterlineskip
\includegraphics{image1}

\includegraphics{image2}

\includegraphics{image3}

\endgroup


\includegraphics{image4}

\includegraphics{image5}


\end{document}
```

Please note: The PDF viewer might show glued lower images too, but this is an PDF viewer issue!. The lower ones are separated!

Answer (score 3):

Here, I just use a `\Shortstack` with 0pt stacking gap.  Default alignment of the stack is centered, but that can be set with `\def\stackalignment{<l,c, or r>}`.

Being a stack, each set of stacked images must fit on a single page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{
\includegraphics[width=1in]{image1}
\includegraphics{image2}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3}
}
%% and a lot more images

\end{document}
```

[image]